# Android camera intent never returns to app

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I have a very frustrating problem. Im using android camera intent to launch the video camera and record a video.

**What I expect:** When I press stop I want to return to my apps activity via the onActivityResult to do some stuff like display a thumb image of the video recording etc.

**What is happening:** When i press stop the screen flashes as if returning to the app but then simply keeps on displaying the camera. I have put a log inside onActivityResult and it never calls back here! Please note, this is not the issue where the intent data == null. This is an issue where the method is never called at all. When i look inside my media directory the video file is in fact there so the recording did take place and stored the file there.

**What im doing:**
    I am calling the camera intent from a button click inside my activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  public void startVideo(){
    //set the path
    String fileName = "MyVid_" + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date()) + ".mp4";
    File externalFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES), fileName);
    Uri videoUri = Uri.fromFile(externalFile)

    //setup up the video intent
    Intent takeVideoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
    takeVideoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, videoUri);
    takeVideoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_SIZE_LIMIT, maxStorage); //set the max file size - variable calculated elsewhere
    takeVideoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_SCREEN_ORIENTATION,   Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE); //set the camera orientation
    takeVideoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_480P); //set the camera resolution
    takeVideoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_SHOW_ACTION_ICONS, true); //set the camera btns

    //start the intent
    if (takeVideoIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(takeVideoIntent, VIDEO_INTENT);
    }
  }

  //then i have the onActivtyResult - this part is never called, regardless of whether data is null or not
  @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      Log.d("***1 LOG onActivityResult - requestCode: ", String.valueOf(requestCode));
  }

}
```

My permissions are as follows:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
```

And my activity that launches the intent is declared as a portrait view in the manifest, although the camera intent is set as landscape in the code as earlier showed:

```
<activity
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
</activity>
```

I am doing something similar for still photos which works like a charm. This code also works fine on the emulator, but when testing on my device (Galaxy S3) it gives this behaviour and only for video. I have searched high and low for a solution but cant find anything, any advice , pointers or links would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: I have found a solution of this issue, please follow the link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36640559/3819836

Answer (score 0):

If you're calling it from a Fragment override the Fragment.onActivityResult() from the Fragment, otherwise you should expect it from the Activity.onActivityResult(). For debug purposes, add logs to both.

And on the Activity one don't forget to call super.onActivityResult() otherwise it might supress the one from the Fragment.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. My code sits inside of an activity MainActivity, so i am not calling it from a fragment at this stage although I will defo keep in mind what you've said once I refactor. At this stage I'm just struggeling to get the app running in its most basic form. Will amend my question to reflect the activity